# Overriding SSH configuration for current environment

Tags: flutter, git, ssh, cicd, ssh-config

#### TL;DR

Is there an option to override the SSH configuration in any way for the current environment only? I.e., provide an option to SSH-Agent, or set environment variable to read SSH config from file, etc, **without** modification of the current user or system configuration of any kind?

#### The Problem

I am trying to set up the CI for one of the repositories I do not own.
During that, a `git clone` command is invoked by a build tool (flutter) to a private repository with a non-standard authentication flow. The cloning process is invoked by a third-party tool during the project dependencies of dependencies download, thus I have no control of the Git URL.

Normal Git authentication (equivalent SSH config):

```
Match Host xxx User git
    User git
    Port 12345
    IdentityFile yyy
```

Normally, the username is `git`, port is 22, and identity file is`~/.ssh/id_rsa`.
A different username & port may be specified in the Git URL, and a different public key may be injected via the SSH Agent.

The problem lies in the fact that private Git repo uses a non-standard SSH model, authenticating users by a "username + ssh key" pair, not only by an SSH key.

The following config is required:

```
Match Host xxx User git
    User username
    Port 12345
    IdentityFile yyy
```

The port specified in the URL is only sometimes correct, and the username is never correct (they include none resulting in the `git` username).

#### What I Tried

I tried the following:

- Injecting an SSH-Agent to provide an SSH key (SSH key includes username) -> didn't work
- Patching the dependencies config in the runtime to change all Git URLs to include the username -> resulted in the successful dependencies but failed on the deps of deps.
- Read all the documentation about the `ssh` CLI, `ssh-agent` CLI, and Flutter (the build tool) -> didn't help

##### Rewriting the URLs:

*Log file is anonymized*

```
[build-multiplatform] [TRACE] Replacing 'ssh://private-repo.org:12345/top-level/dependency' with 'ssh://ci-user@private-repo.org:12345/top-level/dependency'...
[build-multiplatform] Rewriting file 'pubspec.yaml'...
[Pipeline] writeFile
[Pipeline] sh
00:00:15.023  + flutter clean
00:00:15.274  + flutter pub get
00:00:16.186  Resolving dependencies...
00:02:52.433  Git error. Command: `git clone --mirror ssh://private-repo.org/second-level/dependency /home/jenkins/.pub-cache/git/cache/flutter_app_components-323d1175f93598320dc758a60eaf879c64d41c0f`
00:02:52.433  stdout: 
00:02:52.433  stderr: Cloning into bare repository '/home/jenkins/.pub-cache/git/cache/flutter_app_components-323d1175f93598320dc758a60eaf879c64d41c0f'...
00:02:52.433  ssh: connect to host private-repo.org port 22: Connection timed out
00:02:52.433  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
00:02:52.433  
00:02:52.433  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
00:02:52.433  and the repository exists.
00:02:52.433  exit code: 128
```

Note the port (none -> 22) and username (none -> git) in the second-level dependency in the log above.

#### What I can't do

- Modify the global (system) or user SSH or Git configuration (making CI infrastructure-dependent)
- Modify the server authentication model (not having access)
- Modify or override the source code of dependencies, including lists of their dependencies (not having access)
- Modify the build toll (3rd-party)
- Invoke `git clone` manually (requires the reverse engineering of the build tool)
- Add local Git config (cloning is processed to the temporary directory)
- Execute any command as admin/superuser (CI user isn't one)

#### What I can do

- Override any environment variable
- Modify or override top-level source code
- Modify any file in the current directory
- *(Potentially)* Execute build in Docker (requires some additional setup but possible)

Comment: Which CI tool are you working with, and which third-party tool calls the repo?

Comment: Jenkins; flutter. The latter is written in the question BTW